# Recording derivations of previously asserted triples in Jena's rule reasoners?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, jena-rules

I created a Jena Rule Reasoner as in the documentation

```java
final String rules = "[rule1: (?a urn:eg:p ?b) (?b urn:eg:p ?c) -> (?a urn:eg:p ?c)]";
final Reasoner reasoner = new GenericRuleReasoner(Rule.parseRules(rules));
reasoner.setDerivationLogging(true);
final InfModel inf = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, rawData);
```

Everything works fine, and I can check the derivation of triples in the inferred model, but the triples which already exist in `rawData` are not re-inferred by the reasoner, even if they could be, which means that there will be no record of the derivation of such triples.  Is there a way to force the reasoner to re-infer and record derivations of triples that already exist in the raw data?

Comment: To aid in answering this, could you please provide some context as to the goal that will be satisfied by having the reasoner record these derivations? For example, are you attempting to identify triples that, if removed, could/would be re-derived by the current ruleset?

Comment: @RobHall Yes, exactly, I would like to check the derivation path of all triples, even those that could be inferred after being removed

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot think of a way to force Jena to construct the derivations for the information in the raw data. I can, however, think of a brute-force way to cause information to be derived that *could* be derived, thus, resulting in a derivation.

Consider the result of the following (JUnit) test passing:

```java
final Property p = ResourceFactory.createProperty("urn:eg:p");

final Model rawData = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
final Resource a = rawData.createResource("urn:a");
final Resource b = rawData.createResource("urn:b");
final Resource c = rawData.createResource("urn:c");
a.addProperty(p, b);
b.addProperty(p, c);
a.addProperty(p, c);

final String rules = "[rule1: (?a urn:eg:p ?b) (?b urn:eg:p ?c) -> (?a urn:eg:p ?c)]";
final Reasoner reasoner = new GenericRuleReasoner(Rule.parseRules(rules));
reasoner.setDerivationLogging(true);
final InfModel inf = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, rawData);

assertTrue(inf.contains(a,p,c));
final Iterator<Derivation> d0 = inf.getDerivation(inf.asStatement(Triple.create(a.asNode(), p.asNode(), c.asNode())));
assertFalse(d0.hasNext());

inf.remove(a,p,c);

assertTrue(inf.contains(a,p,c));
final Iterator<Derivation> d1 = inf.getDerivation(inf.asStatement(Triple.create(a.asNode(), p.asNode(), c.asNode())));
assertTrue(d1.hasNext());
```

In effect, if you remove a triple from the graph that was presently in the raw data, then, if that triple can be derived, it will remain in the graph. You can then get the derivation. You can safely perform this (costly) operation for all triples in a graph using the following loop:

```java
final Set<Statement> statements = new HashSet<>(rawData.listStatements().toSet());
for( final Statement s : statements ) {
    assert(inf.contains(s));
    inf.remove(s);
    if(!inf.contains(s)) {
        System.out.println("Cannot derive statement from raw data: "+s);
        inf.add(s);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Derivable statement removed from raw data: "+s);
    }
}
```

For the example data above (assuming we remove the everything after the creation of `inf` and replace it with our loop), the output is as follows:

```
Derivable statement removed from raw data: [urn:a, urn:eg:p, urn:c]
Cannot derive statement from raw data: [urn:b, urn:eg:p, urn:c]
Cannot derive statement from raw data: [urn:a, urn:eg:p, urn:b]
```

Your data is now in a state where you can obtain derivations for all derivable things, and only the minimal amount of `rawData` remains that would allow you to conclude the entirety of `inf`.

Note that the behavior of this operation may not be consistent or expected, especially in the presence of multiple derivation paths. Good luck.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I already thought about the solution you gave and as you said it is very costly. I hope someone would give me a better solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If this answer ultimately reflects the solution that you go with, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: As I said, it does not reflect the solution I'll go with, sorry, doing this with large rdf files would be very costly.